# Change AWS Region for Docker CLI context using ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

#### Synopsis

I am using the Docker CLI with the [integration for Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS)](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/). I have set up a Docker context for ECS, however this context is currently pointing to the `us-east-1` AWS region. I would like to update the Docker context for ECS to point to the `us-west-2` region instead.

#### What I've Tried

- Examined the help for the `docker context update` command
- Examined the Docker context JSON file under `~\.docker\contexts\meta\{LongUUID}\meta.json`
- Searched the documentation (linked above) for the word `region`
- Set the `AWS_REGION` environment variable to `us-west-2`

The context "meta" JSON file doesn't contain a property to configure Docker CLI to point to a specific AWS region.

**Question**: How do I update the Docker context to point to a different AWS region, when using the Amazon ECS integration?

Comment: What if you export or set AWS_REGION environment variable on your CLI to us-west-2 ? Does that point Docker CLI to different AWS Region ?

Comment: @aashitvyas I just tried that. Unfortunately it didn't change the region.

Comment: I think you need this environment variable `"AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"`, I have looked at the source code here - https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/ea469249b7895cbedcbea041a6eb746d8972bbf4/ecs/context.go#L47

Comment: @aashitvyas Nope, that didn't work either. If you look at the source code, it first looks for `AWS_REGION` on line 44. However, that's not even working for some reason. https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/ea469249b7895cbedcbea041a6eb746d8972bbf4/ecs/context.go#L44

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that `AWS_REGION` on line 44, after I typed out my last comment. This is very weird and surprising behaviour , I have poked around on GH issues and found this - https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1056 . Hope that helps.